# My owns variables in OSB "Customization File"

Tags: osb

In `Weblogic 12.1.2.0.0` and `OSB : 11.1.1.7` 
How can I put some variables in a proxy or a biz that appears in the "customization file"? Is it even possible?

Comment: I don't think its possible. Usually people create different customization file for each environment.

Answer (score 0):

Realistically, the best option is to use a pre-processor on the customisation file (search and replace script etc, or customise the configjar using [Configurator](https://github.com/tomecode/OSB-Config-WLST-Configurator)) or do something strange, like put the variables in service accounts and pull them out and use them in your proxies.

Answer (score 0):

Common case is to put tokens into customization file and replace it with appropriate value (e.g. for different environment types). You can use maven plugin for it: [maven-replacer-plugin](https://code.google.com/archive/p/maven-replacer-plugin)